# char variable in clause cannot be accessed

Tags: sas, sas-macro

i want to access char variable in where clause like below-->

```
%macro obs(indsn=, outdsn=, clause=, col=, optr=, subset_val=);

data &outdsn;
    set &indsn;
    &clause &col &optr &subset_val;
run;

proc print data= &outdsn;run;

%mend obs;

%obs(indsn=infos, outdsn=ch,clause=where,col=name,optr=?, subset_val=Namo);
```

am trying to incorporate "in contains like" operator in where clause but its not working gives syntax error... but missing eq ne le gt operators are working...
how can I resolve this any help is appreciated.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow!  Your question would be easier to answer if you could post an example (from the log) of the exact syntax error you are receiving..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to pass (quoted) literals where strings are required, eg as follows:

```
%obs(indsn=infos, outdsn=ch,clause=where,col=name,optr=?, subset_val='Namo');
```

Comment: your code IS pretty generic.  I don't think you can really put the quotes in the datastep, as in some cases you may not want the quotes (eg numeric variables) or the quotes may be mixed (eg `where variable in ("don't",'the "don"','etc')` )

Answer (score 1):

You may be aiming for too much automation. Using the fact that WHERE can stand alone, I would suggest a modification as follows:

```
%macro obs(indsn=, outdsn=, filter=);

data &outdsn;
    set &indsn;;
    Where &filter;
run;

proc print data= &outdsn;run;

%mend obs;

%obs(indsn=infos, outdsn=ch, filter=name ? 'Namo');
```

If you end up with really complex filters that are having issues being parsed through you may need to mask the FILTER string

Comment: I agree, I like passing the expression for the where clause in a single parameter, rather than using multiple parameters to pass different terms.  I also like parameter names that are SAS key words, so I would parameterize this as `%obs(data=infos, out=ch, where= name ? 'Namo')`.